# Prototype property with same name as object property

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming

I have a small snippet of code that assigns a prototype property and an object property using the same name. Accessing this `testNumber` after creating the object will always show the object property, which I understand as it will first look for the property on the object and then in the objects prototype, and then the protoype's prototype etc.

But my question is, is there any way to directly access the property of the prototype in this case? [Just a note, I don't know when I would actually need to do this in practice, but it's simply something I'd like to find out for my own sanity].

```
function MyObject1(formalParameter){

    this.testNumber = formalParameter;
}

​MyObject1.prototype.testNumber​ = 55;

var mine = new MyObject1(10);
alert(mine.testNumber);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could access the prototype through the instance's `constructor` property:

```
alert(mine.constructor.prototype.testNumber);
```

Won't work if you've done weird things with the prototype without preserving its `constructor` property, or if you have an instance property called `constructor` for some reason.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. But can you explain what you mean by "If you've done weird things"? Weird things such as what?

Comment: When you create a constructor, its `prototype` object is initialized with a `constructor` property pointing back to the constructor function. If you simply add methods to the prototype you'll be fine, but if you replace the entire prototype (e.g. `Func.prototype = { ... }`), you will need to restore that `constructor` property yourself (`Func.prototype.constructor = Func` after you've redefined the prototype).

Comment: The constructor property is writeable, so you can change it's value, say to reference some other object. Also, the constructor might be assigned a different prototype, so that `obj[[Prototype]]` is not the current `constructor.prototype`.